# Preventing page from refreshing/reloading-ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a countdown counter using React hooks, but while I was comparing its accuracy with its vanilla JS counterpart (I was displaying their current timer on the document title, i.e., I was active on a third tab), I noticed that the react timer stopped after awhile , and when I opened the tab, the page refreshed and the timer reset to its initial state, while this didn't/doesn't happen in the vanilla JS version. I would like to mention that I opened maybe 15 YouTube videos, because I want the timer to be working while doing heavy duty work on my machine. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the code

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import convertTime from '../helper-functions/convertTime';
import useInterval from '../hooks/useInterval';

const Countdown = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(82.5 * 60);
  const [delay, setDelay] = useState(1000);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  document.title = convertTime(count);
  useInterval(() => setCount(count - 1), isPlaying ? delay : null);

  const handlePlayClick = () => setIsPlaying(true);
  const handlePauseClick = () => setIsPlaying(false);

  const handleResetClick = () => {
    setCount(82.5 * 60);
    setDelay(1000);
    setIsPlaying(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className='counter'>
      <div className='time'>{convertTime(count)}</div>
      <div className='actions'>
        <button onClick={handlePlayClick}>play</button>
        <button onClick={handlePauseClick}>pause</button>
        <button onClick={handleResetClick}>reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Countdown;
```

useInterval.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default useInterval;
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @PankajShukla Added.

Comment: It's not clear why this is happening. 
Try to use incognito mode or a different browser

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason why counter should stop.

Comment: I don't know if calling `useEffect` many times **while** the tab is inactive caused this, but the timer did stop, and the page refreshed, and this happened more than once. I wonder if this is a Chrome- or React-related, because I was running many videos at the same time, and maybe the RAM was low, but the timer on vanilla JS didn't stop, so, I am not sure what happened there.